# How to validate dynamically created textbox in gridview using javascript in asp.net web page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, gridview

[image]

I am able to validate the above textbox,ajax dropdownlist but not able to do valiation for Gridview's textbox which is placed inside every cell. I have hidden the textbox border with CSS. I am using Requiredfieldvalidator it is working in Addrow button but if I click Save button to save,it is getting saved with null values in DB.

Comment: Hello,
have you set 'Validation Group' on save button which is given in required field validater?

Comment: @Krunalsinh- Thanks.. your 'Validation Group' Keyword helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically add Validator for each item in your `GridView` as you add `TextBox`.